# What is the solution to this word puzzle?

Tags: word, visual

The word 'Moth' is located left center in the square. In a vertical column at the right side of the square is the word 'cry' written four times. I'm stumped.

Comment: Can we have a picture?

Comment: @Mithrandir What was wrong with "Wuzzle" (i.e., portmanteau of "word puzzle" frequently used to refer to a specific flavor of rebus) in the title? It was more descriptive.

Comment: The solution has to use the words and letters that are given. It is an anagraph type puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

> Mothballs?

Reasoning:

> Moth is obvious, but a synonym for crying is bawling.  Cry = to bawl, multiple 'cry's = bawls.